# How to Unit Test AggregateIterable<User>

Tags: mongodb, mockito, aggregation-framework, testng

Struggling to Mock what to return when using AggregateIterable in Java/Mongo.

I have tried using MongoCursor but struggling to understand this. I want to cover all paths with Unit Tests for this. What are the best possible ways using mockito and testNG.

```
public List<User> getAggregatedList(User user){

  AggregateIterable<User> agg = collection.aggregate(pipeline, User.class)

  List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

  if (agg != null){
    Iterator<User> it = agg.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
      users.add(it.next());
    } 
  }

return users;
}
```

I should be able to write a test such as:

```
...
expected = Arrays.asList(user1,user2...)
verify(result,expect)
```

Comment: What is it you want to test - the return of the getAggregatedList method?  Then you probably want to mock the collection, but your code doesn`t show enough to decide whether it can be mocked or not. Also if the verify method you are refering to is supposed to be Mockito.verify than you have misunderstood the purpose of that method.

Answer (score 3):

You can test it by mocking the hasNext() and next() methods of the iterator like so:

```
@Test
public void testGetAggregatedList() {
    MongoCollection collection = PowerMockito.mock(MongoCollection.class);
    AggregateIterable<User> iterable = PowerMockito.mock(AggregateIterable.class);
    MongoClient client = PowerMockito.mock(MongoClient.class);
    MongoDatabase db = PowerMockito.mock(MongoDatabase.class);
    MongoCursor iterator = PowerMockito.mock(MongoCursor.class);
    User user1 = PowerMockito.mock(User.class);
    User user2 = PowerMockito.mock(User.class);

    MongoDaoDelegator.setClient(client);
    PowerMockito.when(client.getDatabase(anyString())).thenReturn(db);
    PowerMockito.when(db.getCollection(anyString())).thenReturn(collection);
    PowerMockito.when(collection.aggregate(anyList(),any())).thenReturn(iterable);
    PowerMockito.when(iterable.iterator()).thenReturn(iterator);
    PowerMockito.when(iterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true,true,false);
    PowerMockito.when(iterator.next()).thenReturn(user1,user2);

    getAggregatedList(new User()); 
}
```

This will give you the result you are expecting.